# SQL open Excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Excel file on the local C drive and on then network. This is my query

```
select *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\twitter\sqlcheesecake.xlsx'
, [Sheet1$])
```

I can read this file.

If I use the same file on the network and my query:

```
select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=\\twitter\sqlcheesecake.xlsx'
, [Sheet1$])
```

Then I get an error:

> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"

Can any one correct the network path?

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to use it

Comment: can u walk me through

Comment: i can see side by side but dont know how to put on gray box. what is  3 back-ticks ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Missing $ at the end of the  sheet1

Comment: Just delete the question since its a trivial fix.